# Administering IIS with ruby

Tags: ruby, iis, windows-administration

Ill keep this short and simple. I need to find out the steps that I would have to take in order to administer IIS on a windows box using Ruby. The main thing I am trying to achieve is setting an existing websites home directory to a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ruby user, so I am not sure of its power. The basics are that IIS provides a lot of interfaces for administration,

1. ADSI,
2. WMI,
3. Native interface via a few C headers or COM
4. .NET API (provided in IIS 7)

So if ruby can be used to manipulate those interfaces, you can achieve your goal of administration.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9041b0a5-c314-46d9-8f56-01506687f357.mspx?mfr=true

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/173/overview-of-mwa--mwm-for-iis-7/

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/12/Creating-IIS7-sites_2C00_-applications_2C00_-and-virtual-directories.aspx

Comment: The ADSI documentation claims that it can be used with a list of "language[s] that support automation" including Perl. I believe that this provides hope for Ruby.